# PCB design, where to start?

Tags: pcb-design, raspberry-pi, solar-energy, power-management

I am working on a project that requires a power management board. I use a solar panel (or a wind turbine,) a battery and a Raspberry Pi that uses a 4G hat.

I need a board that manages the power source, converts the voltage out of the solar panel (or from AC power) and the battery to 5V and sends feedback to the Raspberry Pi about the battery charge or the solar panel efficiency.

I studied electrical engineering for 2 years but is was 25 years ago and I never used it in my professional life as I became a software engeneer.

I don't know where to start to design my own board by myself. I found some information about what components would be useful (such as INA260 for power measurement) but what are the online tools and the ressources that you can use when you want to design something like that and you're not a pro?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a shopping question because you are seeking recommendations where to find stuff. Site rule: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.*

Comment: I do not plan to shop anything... I just need some help to find ressources to be able to start desining... It is not about stuff, it is about methods, knowledge and tools.....

Comment: Plenty of hobbyists that never studied EE have designed (simple) boards successfully. I suggest that you search fora like EEVBlog to see what they use. Also, if you search for "PCB design tool" you get a list of tools that exist. It is easy to then find out which ones are suitable for what purpose (pro/hobbyist) and what they cost (pro tools are not free). But designing the PCB is only one part. A PCB is only that what connects the components in a **circuit**. Designing the **circuit** is generally the most difficult task which may require lots of studying depending on what you want.

Comment: I also suggest that you "let go" of your assumption that you need "a powermanagement board" and an RPi and a 4G hat. First have a look at similar projects (like on instuctables.com) and see how these are build and try to understand why things are done the way that they are.

Comment: The question is slightly misleading. You don't actually need help with PCB design. You need to design the schematics, i.e. the actual device first, to start implementing a PCB design for it.

Comment: @Romk it's still a shopping question.

Comment: @Andyaka ... Define shopping ? :-D

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, thx a lot for your answer, it gives me somewhere to start. And your right, I think my question is more about circuit designing... But I'm not a natural born english speaker... ;-)

Comment: Start with power specs for impedance matching the load to the solar current source then specs for battery voltage regulation and current control. CC, CV cutoff with battery current separate from load current. Simulate it then decide if the design works before PCB design

Comment: @Romk any question that primarily seeks a product or service recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to start with a breadboard and jumpers.

Look for schematics on the internet of designs similar to yours and mostly copy them, making changes as necessary to adapt to your application.

Buy the components from mouser or digikey. Make sure to get through-hole parts. Check out sites like sparkfun and adafruit for "friendlier" (but fewer) options.

Get it working on a breadboard (it probably won't work the first try if you're rusty).

Then make a schematic of your breadboard design.

..Now you're ready to start thinking about making a PCB.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is don't try to re-invent the wheel. Create your own circuit only for things that don't exist yet and are specific to your need.
Buy off the shelf power converters, a Raspberry module and other things that you can find ready to use, then connect these things together. Do a PCB for the things which you can't find. Reduce your work and increase reliability.

If you really want to combine everything on a single PCB, it's possible, but be prepared to spend a lot of time learning, reading and understanding everything, choosing components, testing, fixing mistakes etc...

[For starting with PCB design, I recommend FreePCB-2](https://freepcb.dev/)